# Google Sheet if value matches values in list

Tags: google-sheets

My data looks like this.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | Credit Card |
| 2 | 200 | Debit Card |
| 3 | 1000 | Pay Later |

I want to sum of column `B` entries where the corresponding value in `C` is either "Credit Card", "Pay Later" (May have more values in future).

How do I calculate `total debt` in the above data?

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dWb7XFoUVeYxBazqz2CKMSgAr8lg9zfTswBG5n3xRiA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It is unclear whether you want a single result or multiple row-by-row results. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: @doubleunary Apologies for that. I've changed the description of the question and added a simple spreadsheet as well. I hope that helps.

Comment: Edited the answer to match your new requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter()` with `regexmatch()`, like this:

`=sum( iferror( filter( C7:C, regexmatch(D7:D, "(?i)credit card|pay.?later") ) ) )`

Comment: Just for clarification: The purpose of `iferror(1/0)`, as I understand it, is that it returns a blank cell. An alternative would be to use `''` to create an an empty string but this would be included in any `counta` function.

Comment: Yes — `iferror(1/0)` gets a truly blank value, which is different from the zero-length text string `""`. Truly blank values do not consume storage space while zero-length text strings do. You can test cells for blankness with `isblank()`.

Comment: This helps me @doubleunary. Thanks for the answer!